VBA read 1st line of large utf8 csv
I tried to use th ADODB to read only the first line of a large utf8 file.
for my purpose I need only the values of the first line in a csv (having the headers of a table)
Public Sub stream()
    Fullpath = "path to File"
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    stream.Charset = "utf-8"
    stream.Open
    stream.LoadFromFile Fullpath

    txt=stream.ReadText (-2) 'read only one line
    
End Sub

when it comes to the line stream.ReadText excel freezes. (the file is about 400 MB)
Any idea how to read only the first line of big files?

Only a guess, but it could be a problem with the line ending definition. If the CSV was written on a Unix/Linux machine, it will probably have only <LF> as line end character. If it comes from a Mac, usually it has only <CR>.
Now if you open the stream, it will read data until it finds the first line ending. On windows, the default is <CR><LF> - however if the line ending in your CSV file is either only <CR> or <LF>, the stream will never find a line ending and therefore will read the whole file.
You can change the expected line ending with the property LineSeparator of the stream.
stream.LineSeparator = adCR

or
stream.LineSeparator = adLF

or
stream.LineSeparator = adCRLF

(Do this before you read data)
As you are using late binding, the constants are probably not defined, so add the the declarations at the top of your code:
Const adCR = 13
Const adLF = 10
Const adCRLF = -1

